# How to avoid spark shuffle with an union on 2 bucketized dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, shuffle

I have 2 dataframes that were bucketed on the same col.

```
scala> (1 to 10).map(i => (i, "element"+i))
res21: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, String)] = Vector((1,element1), (2,element2), (3,element3), (4,element4), (5,element5), (6,element6), (7,element7), (8,element8), (9,element9), (10,element10))

scala> spark.createDataFrame(res21).toDF("a", "b")
res22: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: string]

scala> res22.write.bucketBy(2, "a").saveAsTable("tab1")
17/10/17 23:07:50 WARN HiveExternalCatalog: Persisting bucketed data source table `default`.`tab1` into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive.

scala> res22.write.bucketBy(2, "a").saveAsTable("tab2")
17/10/17 23:07:54 WARN HiveExternalCatalog: Persisting bucketed data source table `default`.`tab2` into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive.
```

If I perform an union of those dataframes, Spark is not able anymore to avoid shuffle.

```
scala> spark.table("tab1").union(spark.table("tab2")).groupBy("a").count().explain(true)
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[a#149], functions=[count(1)], output=[a#149, count#166L])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#149, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[a#149], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[a#149, count#172L])
      +- Union
         :- *FileScan parquet default.tab1[a#149] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/yann.moisan/projects/teads/data/spark-warehouse/tab1], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<a:int>
         +- *FileScan parquet default.tab2[a#154] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/yann.moisan/projects/teads/data/spark-warehouse/tab2], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<a:int>
```

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I am having the same question